# Problem with location permission during first time launch only in simulator iPhone6 - XCode 9.4.1

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I have one weird problem. 
The problem occurs only in iPhone6 simulator.
When i started app first time, without permission, then show fail in this code. This code located in ViewDidLoad in main ViewController

```
manager.delegate = self
manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
manager.startUpdatingLocation()
var curLoc:CLLocation!
curLoc = manager.location
mapView.delegate = self
if (isLocationPermissionGranted() == false){
         MapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.406464, longitude: 16.924997), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)), animated: true)
        }else
        {
         MapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(curLoc.coordinate.latitude, curLoc.coordinate.longitude), MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)), animated: true)
        }

        let getJSON = JSONDownload()
        getJSON.JSONDownloader(MapView: MapView)
    }
```

In else block I have error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

But in any other simulator or my phone(iPhone 6s, iOS 11.4.1) only show

> Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4

About this message I'm little confused too, because, I suppose, I have every permission option.

My permission stuff is:

in Info.plist

> Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
>
> Privacy - Location Usage Description

In code in ViewController

```
let manager = CLLocationManager()
```

In addition, I have protection against localized errors:

```
func isLocationPermissionGranted() -> Bool{
guard CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() else{
    return false
}
return [.authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse].contains(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus())
}
```

Is any chance to fix it? :)
Thanks for answer! :)

Comment: Is `MapView` (which by convention should be `mapView`) an `@IBOutlet`? or otherwise an implicitly unwrapped optional? - It seems that at the point you are calling this code `MapView` is `nil`

Comment: Yes, I have @IBOutlet weak var MapView: MKMapView!
And everything works fine, like show annotation or show current location.
And I learn convention, will be useful for the future, thanks :)

Comment: So, where are you running that code? `viewWillAppear`? `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: In `viewDidLoad`. I have `manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest`, `manager.startUpdatingLocation()`, `var curLoc:CLLocation!`, `curLoc = manager.location`, `mapView.delegate = self`, and after that block of code with error :)

Comment: You should edit your question to add that context and code, because it is important.

Comment: Add some information. I hope is better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are declaring `curLoc` as an implicitly unwrapped optional and then assigning `manager.location` to it; but `manager.location` is an optional and may be `nil`.  There are a number of reasons that `location` could be `nil`; It takes time for a device to determine its location or the user may have denied location access.

Whatever the reason, when you subsequently access `curLoc` when it contains `nil` you get an exception because the contract of an implicitly unwrapped optional is that it won't be `nil`.

You need to unwrap `manager.location` safely in order to avoid a crash.

```
mapView.delegate = self

if let curLoc = manager.location, isLocationPermissionGranted() {         
    MapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(curLoc.coordinate.latitude, curLoc.coordinate.longitude), MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)), animated: true)
} else {
    MapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.406464, longitude: 16.924997), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I changed it and simulator don't crashed, but still I have error `Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4`

Comment: You can ignore that; it is just some logging from MapKit.